# Firebase query on multiple filters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have the following firebase data structure:

```
Games
    --- 20190220000_NCAA (SportID)
        --- WeekId : 1
        --- etc...
    --- 20190221000_NCAA
        --- WeekId : 2
        --- etc...
    --- 20190204000_NFL    
        --- WeekId : 1
        --- etc...
    --- etc...(SportsID)
```

So what I am trying to achieve is something like: Get all the Games that are NCAA related to week = 1

Which should only return 20190220000_NCAA based on the example above.

The query I have is the following:

```
gamesRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryStarting(atValue: "_NCAA").queryEnding(atValue: "_NCAA\u{f8ff}").queryOrdered(byChild: "WeekId").queryEqual(toValue: "1").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
```

So if I understand it correctly it should query all 'Keys' with _NCAA as a substring and then also order the result by Week id = 1 with the 'Keys' that have '_NCAA' as substring?!

The problem is that it does not return the correct result.

Does anyone have any insight on how can I achieve my query?

Comment: what does it return ?

Comment: it return both : 20190220000_NCAA and 20190204000_NFL

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show shouldn't event compile. Firebase Database queries can only contain a single `orderBy...` clause, and can never do suffix matching (your `_NCAA` is at the end of the key).

To allow you use-case you should have a key/property that consists of the week number, and the org (`NCAA`/`NFL`) value. E.g.

```
Games
    --- 20190220000_NCAA (SportID)
        --- WeekId : 1
        --- WeekOrg : "01_NCAA"
        --- etc...
    --- 20190221000_NCAA
        --- WeekId : 2
        --- WeekOrg : "02_NCAA"
        --- etc...
    --- 20190204000_NFL    
        --- WeekId : 1
        --- WeekOrg : "01_NFL"
        --- etc...
    --- etc...(SportsID)
```

With this in place you can get the nodes in week 1 for the NCAA with:

```
gamesRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "WeekOrg").queryEqual(toValue: "01_NCAA").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
```

Also see my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase